# Implementing generic TS function for dispatching events

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to implement a generic function that will be used across the application for dispatching events. My idea was to make it similar to Redux dispatch, where a user can specify a type and payload, and the handler takes care of the rest. In general, I planned to do the following:

*Implement handlers and create a map for them*

```
const sendEventA = (payload: {key: string}) => null
const sendEventB = (payload: {id: number}) => null

const eventHandlersMap = {
  EventA: sendEventA,
  EventB: sendEventB,
}
```

*Implement dispatch function itself*

```
const myDispatch = (type, payload) => {
  const handler = eventHandlersMap[type]
  
  handler(payload)
}
```

I'm having issues with making types work correctly inside the dispatch function:

```
type MyEvent = keyof typeof eventHandlersMap 
type HandlerPayload<T extends MyEvent> = Parameters<(typeof eventHandlersMap)[T]>[0]

const myDispatch = <T extends MyEvent>(type: T, payload: HandlerPayload<T>) => {
  const handler = eventHandlersMap[type]

  handler(payload)
       // ^Property 'id' is missing in type '{ key: string; }' but required in type '{ id: number; }'
}
```

Even though types work correctly when calling the function

```
myDispatch('EventA', {key: 'str'})
myDispatch('EventB', {id: 5})
```

Comment: This is ms/TS#30581 and the recommended approach is ms/TS#47109. See the linked q/a above for more information.